# display duplicate values when checked two binding checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

my two synchronized checkbox displayed duplicate values when checked, how to fix it? I just want to show one single value of each checkbox
see the demo
http://jsfiddle.net/HvKmE/1127/
seems need more words to ask a question...

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  var selector = $(this).data('selector');
  $('[data-selector="' + selector + '"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var values = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(',');
  $('p').html(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CS-popup" class="popup-windows ">
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC01" data-selector="GMSC01BOX-1">GMSC01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC02" data-selector="GMSC02BOX-1">GMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC01" data-selector="VMSC01BOX-1">VMSC01
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC02" data-selector="VMSC02BOX-1">VMSC02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW01" data-selector="GMGW01BOX-1">GMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW02" data-selector="GMGW02BOX-1">GMGW02
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW01" data-selector="VMGW01BOX-1">VMGW01
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW02" data-selector="VMGW02BOX-1">VMGW02
  <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS01" data-selector="SPS01BOX-1">SPS01

  <br>
</div>
<div>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne015" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMSC01BOX-1" value="GMSC01">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne016" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMSC02BOX-1" value="GMSC02">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne017" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMSC01BOX-1" value="VMSC01">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne018" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMSC02BOX-1" value="VMSC02">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne019" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMGW01BOX-1" value="GMGW01">
    </TD1 <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne020" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMGW02BOX-1" value="GMGW02">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne021" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMGW01BOX-1" value="VMGW01">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne022" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMGW02BOX-1" value="VMGW02">
  </TD>
  <TD class="col-ne col-CS">
    <INPUT name="cf_ne023" type="checkbox" data-selector="SPS01BOX-1" value="SPS01">
    <p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that you don't need to two separate `change` event handlers. They both point to the same elements, so you can combine them.

Secondly, your HTML is invalid as you cannot have a `td` element as a child of a `div`. It need to be contained within a `table`, `tbody`, then `tr`. The `p` element also needs to be moved outside of that `table`. You should also wrap the checkboxes and their associated text nodes in `label` elements to increase their hit area as a courtesy to your users.

To fix the issue of duplicate values appearing, simply make the `:checkbox` selector more specific; restrict it to the `#CS-popup` element for example:

```
var values = $('#CS-popup :checkbox:checked').map(function() ...
```

Here's a full working example with the JS and HTML corrected:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var selector = $(this).data('selector');
  $('[data-selector="' + selector + '"]').prop("checked", this.checked);

  var values = $('#CS-popup :checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join(',');
  $('p').html(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CS-popup" class="popup-windows ">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC01" data-selector="GMSC01BOX-1" />
    GMSC01
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMSC02" data-selector="GMSC02BOX-1" />
    GMSC02
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC01" data-selector="VMSC01BOX-1" />
    VMSC01
  </label><br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMSC02" data-selector="VMSC02BOX-1">
    VMSC02
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW01" data-selector="GMGW01BOX-1" />
    GMGW01
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="GMGW02" data-selector="GMGW02BOX-1" />
    GMGW02
  </label><br />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW01" data-selector="VMGW01BOX-1" />
    VMGW01
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="VMGW02" data-selector="VMGW02BOX-1" />
    VMGW02
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="CS" value="SPS01" data-selector="SPS01BOX-1" />
    SPS01
  </label><br />
</div>
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne015" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMSC01BOX-1" value="GMSC01" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne016" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMSC02BOX-1" value="GMSC02" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne017" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMSC01BOX-1" value="VMSC01" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne018" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMSC02BOX-1" value="VMSC02" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne019" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMGW01BOX-1" value="GMGW01" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne020" type="checkbox" data-selector="GMGW02BOX-1" value="GMGW02" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne021" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMGW01BOX-1" value="VMGW01" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne022" type="checkbox" data-selector="VMGW02BOX-1" value="VMGW02" />
        </td>
        <td class="col-ne col-CS">
          <input name="cf_ne023" type="checkbox" data-selector="SPS01BOX-1" value="SPS01" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<p></p>
```